# Publish to facebook group as user - not as group?

Tags: android, facebook

I am able to publish at message på the groups wall as the group(with permissions publish_actions, publish_stream and manage_pages), but I can't figure out how to do it as my personal user. 
My goal is to make it possible for every one that likes the group to post on it with the app.

How to do that? - can't seem find any anything about it..

Code to publish with facebook api 3.0:

```
Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "group-id/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

Comment: Being able to post 'as' the group shouldn't be possible, are you sure you're not confusing your terminology?

Comment: You are right in some ways. I tried to post to the group(which is actually a place) with as user that wasn't admin in the group, and then it worked as it was supposed to. But it seems that when you are admin on a group, you automatically post as the group and not as you personal user, with the same permissions.

Comment: I still suspect you're saying 'group' when you mean 'page'

Comment: You might be right - what is the difference?

Comment: The features and design of both have changed a lot since this was posted, but it gives a good summary: https://www.facebook.com/blog/blog.php?post=324706977130